# Making WordPress Gallery (.gallery-item) Responsive?

Tags: images, css, gallery, responsive

Shortcode for Gallery: `[gallery link="file" columns="5" size="medium"]`

I’m using a 5 column gallery on an inner page of a website, obviously when the site responds down to mobile and even tablet devices, the images within the gallery keep the default style of `width: 20%;` and appear far too small.

I have tried adding a media query style to increase the width in percentage, however WP still applies the column class `.gallery-columns-5`.

Ideally It would be great to have the images in 5 Columns for Desktop's, 3 Columns for Tablet's and 1 Column for Mobile Devices.

Would anyone know of a good fix for this?

```
/ ## Gallery
--------------------------------------------- */

.gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery-item {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item {
    width: 20%;
}

.gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item:nth-child(2n+1),
.gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item:nth-child(3n+1),
.gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item:nth-child(4n+1),
.gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item:nth-child(5n+1),
.gallery-columns-6 .gallery-item:nth-child(6n+1),
.gallery-columns-7 .gallery-item:nth-child(7n+1),
.gallery-columns-8 .gallery-item:nth-child(8n+1),
.gallery-columns-9 .gallery-item:nth-child(9n+1) {
    clear: left;
}

.gallery img {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4px;
}

.gallery img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)

.gallery-item {
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: @ManojKumar Updated.

Comment: If you want to remove the class just filter it out: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gallery_style/ or create your own template-gallery.php file (I havent tried this yet but I assume it works like the rest of wordpress)

Comment: Send me the URL of the gallery page @Tom25

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple solution for this. Let the gallery use the 5 column grid system and using the `@media-queries` we can alter it for tablet and mobile. I just tested it on your given URL and it works perfect. But try to remove any custom codes you have used before since I had to remove it in order to use the following code.

```
/* For displaying 3 columns on tablet */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item {
     width: 33%;
 }
}

/* For displaying single column on mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item {
     width: 100%;
 }
}

.gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item:nth-child(5n+1) {
     clear: none;
}
```

Comment: This is better, but it still leaves the white space and is being treated as 5 columns on tablet devices. It almost looks like there is an image missing. I have updated the code...

Comment: Code updated. This should fill the blank space.

Comment: @streetfire No problem mate! :)

Comment: Nice. You can stack this up to cover all galleries: .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item , .gallery-columns-6 .gallery-item , .gallery-columns-7 .gallery-item

Comment: It seems WordPress has changed their code and now instead of having `width` above you need `max-width`.